# Area 51 and MSO favicon not present on the flair

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, meta, flair

This sounds trivial but I want to ask. I have placed flairs of Stackexchange sites on my personal web page. All flairs have the related favicon on them (on the left side of user name) except Area 51 and Meta Stackoverflow. On the other hand, I can see the favicons on the [user flair](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair) page.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: No repro on `mehper.tr.gg/Home-Page.htm` FF 3.6 XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after the latest update on beta sites' favicons, the problem vanished on my website.

Answer (score 1):

Your flairs look ok on your account page, though -- and that's the same sort of `<iframe>`.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140794?tab=accounts#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for the official flair, but have you tried [StackImage flair](http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com)? It's an image-based flair that you can stick anywhere images are permitted.

*Note: I am the creator of this tool.*

*2<sup>nd</sup> Note: This tool supports Meta, but not Area51. (Yet.)*

Comment: It supports Area51 now.