# Global inbox still uses old SE beta favicons

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, global-inbox

All SE betas now boast ad-hoc favicons: [image]   [image]   [image]   [image]   [image] ...

The global inbox, however, does not:

[image: The global inbox]

Indeed, it seems to use `http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/img/favicon.ico` instead.

Comment: Works for me, also duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61504/area-51-and-mso-favicon-not-present-on-the-flair

Comment: Okay, deduplicating. @bobby Done.

Comment: Add stackexchange.com as site too, as it uses the old icons as well.

Comment: @Ralph that's interesting. I can't repro old favicons in SE.com and Bobby can't repro old favicons in flair. I guess caching is glitching up a little somewhere.

Comment: @badp - It only happens on `all sites`and `top users` for me. Might well be a caching problem.

Comment: @Ralph good catch. I also have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in the repo, will go out sometime tonight.

Comment: +1 You guys are really on the ball with this favicon issue, huh?

Comment: Is the duplication of entries issue fixed also?