# No avatar on Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, profile-picture

So I was playing around on Area 51 hoping for further news on the private beta for ebooks, and noticed that my avatar (a hand) was missing. Also the Area 51 has the old toolbar. So I looked at the flair page. The network flair has my hand, the Area 51 flair has a quilt. OK, so time to upload a new image, and WordPress -- WordPress -- I don't want to login to WordPress. Any idea what's up with that?

The following questions did not help, and have different causes and symptoms:

- [Area 51 and MSO favicon not present on the flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61504/area-51-and-mso-favicon-not-present-on-the-flair)
- [What happened to my flair?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129520/what-happened-to-my-flair)

Comment: *and noticed that my hand was missing* <-- I stopped reading right there.

Comment: @UndotheSnowman I use a hand for my avatar, and I edited the question, thanks for telling me where the problem was.

Comment: That's better ;)

Comment: What happened im between you deciding to upload and image and ending up at WordPress wherever?

Comment: I was on my user page, clicked edit which brought me to the edit page, clicked upload image, a new tab opened with a partial bio of a wordpress founder.

Comment: @animuson gravatar now uses a wordpress login but you can still log in with your original gravatar credentials

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately Area51 is running on older Stack Exchange "engine", or technically speaking different, older, codebase. (I won't get into why it's so, it's big enough for a separate discussion which likely already exists)

This means most new features we see on other sites are not making it to Area51.

On all sites you're using "custom" picture as your avatar, [this is a pretty recent feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161083/152859):

> [image]

As you can see, Area51 does not have that feature and its avatar is served only by http://www.gravatar.com/ which walks hand in hand with WordPress [for many years now](http://blog.gravatar.com/2013/04/03/gravatar-and-wordpress-com-together-forever/).

Use it or don't use it, that of course is up to you. Gravatar is still used by great many sites, personally can't see any reason to fear it and if you're really paranoid create new email account for Gravatar, put your hand there and change your avatar across all sites to use it.